# Matlab "for" vs "while"

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab, programming

I am trying to solve the system by Jacobi method.

\begin{align*}
5x-y+z&=10\\
2x+8y-z&=11\\
-x+y+4z&=3
\end{align*}

So I wrote the following Matlab code.

[image]
[image]
[image]
Now when I run this, only one iterate is given. But I am expecting multiple iterates approaching exact solution.

But when I use "for" loop, it gives multiple iterates.
[image]

What am I doing wrong with "while" loop?

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure what you're trying to do exactly, but I see that at the end of your while loop, you say x0=x. Then you ask if norm(x-x0)/norm(x)=norm(x-x)/norm(x)=norm(0)/norm(x) > tolerance....

Comment: Basically, If you are even doing loops in Matlab you are usually doing something wrong.

Comment: No loops? Do you even code?

Comment: @Math_QED: I have coded in many languages. A for-loop in Matlab is one too many. The overhead is very slow compared to the vectorized instructions. Often can be 100 or 1000 times slower if you have 2 or 3 nested loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your while loop, you set `x0=x` which means that `x-x0=0` up to machine precision. This means that `norm(x-x0)=norm(0)` which will obviously satisfy the while condition and break from the loop. Your for loop does not have this problem, since you compute `x` before setting it equal to `x0` with your if comparison. Basically, your while loop should work if you switch the order of your two statements.